# ASP.NET Core jQuery .ajax post always null?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core 3.1
jQuery 3.3.1

I've cut down my code to the bare bones, My client side JavaScript looks like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/xxx/Edit",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify("Hello"),
        success: function (result) {

            //
        },
        error: function (jqXHR) {

            //
        }
```

My server-side Controller Action code is:

```
// xxx controller
public async Task<JsonResult> Edit(string data)
{
    ...
    await ...
}
```

The value of data is always **null**.  It should be "Hello".

In the real code the data is not simply a string, it is a complex type, but I have found that even with a simple string (as with a complex type) the action parameter is null???

Anyone have any ideas why the controller action does not receive "Hello" in its parameter?

Comment: Your `url:` is missing a question mark at the end of the line (but I suspect this isn't your issue).

Comment: Try putting `data: { arg: "Hello" }` and then in your controller change `string data` to `string arg`. Just to make sure it's pulling through the data.

Comment: Typo.  Incidentally... I'm migrating this from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core.  Same code worked fine on ASP.NET.

Comment: `data: { data: 'Hello' }` and get rid of `contentType`. Also ensure that your action is configured to receive POST requests

Comment: arg is still null when it reaches the controller action..

Comment: `[HttpPost]` attribute is missing on the controller method

Comment: ^ That might help

Comment: Doing what Halden and Cory said (along with removing content type) seems to have fixed the string and has fixed the complex type too.  Thanks guys.

Comment: No worries, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "xxx/Edit".
            type: "POST",
            data: { data: "Hello" },  // named parameter and contentType removed
            success: function (result) {

                //
            },
            error: function (jqXHR) {

                //
            }
        });
```

and controller action...

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> Edit(string data)
```